# Get a list of replacement fields from a Python string

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a string like this:

```
my_str = '{one}, {two}, {three}'
print(my_str.format(one=1, two=2, three=3)) #1, 2, 3
```

I would like a list of replacement fields in my string:

```
get_replacement_fields(my_str) # ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

I define "replacemente fields" the minimal set of fields you have to pass to the `.format()` method to get a valid return. For example,

```
print(my_str.format(one=1, two=2)) # KeyError
print(my_str.format(one=1, two=2, three=3, four=4)) # 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: What is the definition of a "replacement field", and how did you try to implement this?

Comment: Best implementation that comes to mind is through re, but I am wondering if there is a more established way

Comment: `D = collections.defaultdict(str); my_str.format_map(D); print(D.keys())`.  Might not work if you're using some more advanced features of `.format()`.

Comment: @jasonharper: You should post that as an answer, it's substantially more complete and less fragile than any of the regex solutions already posted.

Comment: @jasonharper Agreed with ShadowRanger, please, post your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Function get_replacement_fields uses a regular expression pattern to find all occurrences of words enclosed in curly braces {}.

```
import re

def get_replacement_fields(string):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\{(\w+)\}')
    return pattern.findall(string)

my_str = '{one}, {two}, {three}'
print(get_replacement_fields(my_str))
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This is going to work in only the most basic of cases; if any of the fields have formatting applied, it immediately fails. Regex are not the solution in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) (that should not start with a digit) you might use a regex like:

```
\{([^\W\d]\w*)}
```

The pattern matches:

- `\{` Match `{`
- `(` Capture **group 1**, which will be returned by re.findall

  - `[^\W\d]\w*` Match a word char other than a digit, followed by matching optional word chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `}` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZ3ctm/1)

You could pass a dict to [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), but that by itself can throw an Exception, which you can handle the way you seem fit:

For example:

```
import re

strings = [
    '{one}, {two}, {three}',
    '{one}, {two}',
    '{one}, {1}',  # Exception IndexError
    '{one}, {two}, {one}',
    '{one}, {two}, {three}, {four}'  # Exception KeyError
]

lst = [1, 2, 3]


def get_custom_formatted_string(s, values):
    keyword_args = re.findall(r"\{([^\W\d]\w*)}", s)
    dct = {k: v for k, v in zip(keyword_args, values)}
    try:
        return s.format(**dct)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"[Exception type: {type(e)} for string: '{s}']")
        return s


for s in strings:
    print(get_custom_formatted_string(s, lst))
```

Output

```
1, 2, 3
1, 2
[Exception type: <class 'IndexError'> for string: '{one}, {1}']
{one}, {1}
3, 2, 3
[Exception type: <class 'KeyError'> for string: '{one}, {two}, {three}, {four}']
{one}, {two}, {three}, {four}
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IS0rjP)